# Initializing a serialization object with an array

Tags: c#, arrays, serialization

I'm very new to working with serialization and in particular working with xsd.exe to generate serialization classes. I'Ve created a class from XSD.exe and am trying to intialise it as follows:

```
        Export mainExportNode = new Export();

        mainExportNode.header = new exportHeader()
        {
            uniqueId = "1111",
            //...more values to initialize.
        };
        mainExportNode.item = new exportItem[]
        {
            //Need to know how to init more than one 'exportItem'
            //The values for this are name, position and area
        };
        mainExportNode.file = new exportFile[]
        {
            //Need to know how to init more than one 'exportFile'
            //The values for this are name, type and data.
        };

        //Serialize to XML file
        var s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Export));
        using (var f = File.Open("export.xml", FileMode.Create))
        {
            s.Serialize(f, mainExportNode);
        }
```

Where I'm currently stuck is the 'unbounded' elements which require 1 or more repeating elements of the same type. I need to know what the best way to initialise these as with the structure above i'm currently unsure as to how i can initialise more than one instance of the ExportItem and ExportFile.

I understand i need to take two arrays with the respective values for Item and File and somehow use this to loop and add multiple ExportItem and ExportFile, I'm sure it's pretty simple but I'm not exactly sure how i can do this.

Can anyone advise?

Thanks.